# Entity Framework 7 migration: how to get a varchar column with a length greater than 1?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-migrations, varchar, maxlength, entity-framework-core

I have the following:

```
[Table("Countries")]
public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255), Required]
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

Every time I apply my migration, CountryCode becomes a varchar column with a max length of 1. I tried setting the MaxLength annotation to 255 and still get a max length of 1. When the column is set as nvarchar it works as expected. Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: Whenever I explicitly set the string data type, length sets to 1. I could have used Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")] and the length sets as 1..

Comment: Try `[Column(TypeName = "varchar(255)")]`

Comment: I tried that too. Didn't work. Still produces a length of 1.

Comment: Add atribute `[StringLength(250)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would of liked to have used data annotations, but I was able to get it to work with:

```
 builder.Entity<Country>()
            .Property(e = e.CountryCode).HasSqlServerColumnType("VARCHAR(30)");
```

> Data Annotations are not yet fully implemented in Entity Framework 7.
>   You can still add annotations to your entity classes so that they are
>   used by other frameworks (such as ASP.NET MVC), but Entity Framework
>   will not process these annotations. You can track support for Data
>   [Annotations on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/107).

http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/configuring.html

Answer (score 0):

OK using .net core 2 targeting sql server I had this issue. My model builder looked like this.

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<StreamCheckpointDto>()
            .Property(e => e.StreamName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(40).IsUnicode(false);
```

Once I removed the HasColumnType and let it choose varchar automatically based on my StreamCheckpointDto.StreamName being a string the length became 40 as expected. you might also be able to use.

```
.HasColumnType("varchar(40)")
```

instead.